# Select Group data with one matching condition

Tags: sql

Table:

```
Col1 Col2
1     2
1     3
1     4
2     2
2     3
```

first need to check all rows with col2 = 4 
Then need to select all rows with values col1

The result should be:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

Comment: Print_r() your records so we can help you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head

```
SELECT A.* FROM MyTable A JOIN MyTable B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1 WHERE B.Col2 = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col1 in (select t2.col1 from t t2 where t2.col2 = 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query checks on both columns, where col2 = 4 and col1 = 1, from what i can understand in your description.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2 FROM Table t1
WHERE t1.col2 = 4
UNION
SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2 FROM Table t2
WHERE t2.col1 = 1
```